# Most concise way to take props in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

The most concise syntax I know for writing a React component, is the following, which always names every input parameter twice.

```
export function InputXl({
  placeholder,
  value,
}: {
  placeholder: string;
  value: string;
}): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Input placeholder={placeholder} value={value} size="xl" />
  );
}
```

Is there a syntax where I only have to name the parameters once? Something like:

```
export function InputXl({
  placeholder: string;
  value: string;
}): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Input placeholder={placeholder} value={value} size="xl" />
  );
}
```

Comment: did you try declare type of your props separately ?

Answer (score 1):

If you using typescript You can define your component props type like this:

```
type InputXlProps = {
  value: string;
  placeholder: string;
};

export function InputXl(props: InputXlProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Input placeholder={props.placeholder} value={props.value} size="xl" />
  );
}
```

or:

```
export function InputXl({ value, placeholder }: InputXlProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Input placeholder={props.placeholder} value={props.value} size="xl" />
  );
}
```

At the end It's discouraged to use React.Fc and you can see the reasons here:

[Remove React.FC from Typescript template](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177)

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be the most concise:

```
type InputXlProps = {
  value: string;
  placeholder: string;
};

export const InputXl: React.FC<InputXlProps> = (props) => (
  <Input placeholder={props.placeholder} value={props.value} size="xl" />
);
```